# In Swift, can you pass nil as an input to a function?

Tags: objective-c, oop, swift, design-patterns, null

I'm reading many articles about how you shouldn't check an object for nil. It's a objC paradigm and it's a bad design and w/ swift it's been eliminated. So my question is, per example below, can you pass thru "group" as nil value? does the nil-checking mechanism happen when the function is called, hence removing the need to implement if(group==nil){..} ?

```
func deleteMembershipForGroup(group:GroupData){
}
```

Comment: Where have you heard that 'nil' is "an Objective-C paradigm", "it's a bad design" and "with Swift it's been eliminated"? Java has 'null', 'nil' makes perfect sense in many cases (and particularly with respect to sending messages to 'nil'), and Swift has optionals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use an optional:

```
func deleteMembershipForGroup(group:GroupData?){
  if let groupReal = group {
  // not nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Thomas Kilian is right and it works for me! You will then be able to pass a nil parameter. You will also notice that using optional variable, it will also removed the warning saying the variable "group" will always be true.

```
func deleteMembershipForGroup(group:GroupData?){
   if let groupReal = group { <--- Warning gone!
   // not nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? I just want to provide confirmation and extra information to what Thomas said as answer